# Удалять из одного стейта и помещать удаленные значения в другой

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Всем привет. Очень нужна помощь. Задача - есть таблица, в ней выбираются чекбоксами строки, нажимается кнопка переместить - и эти значения удаляются из первой таблицы и кладутся во вторую.

дано: dirline, dirline2  - это два стейта
e.dirline_id = key( key это выбранный чекбокс, e.dirline_id - с сервака приходит изначально, он равен кею.

```
dirline = [{ e.dirline_id, value }, { e.dirline_id, value }, { e.dirline_id, value }]
dirline2 = []
```

Задача: удалять из `dirline` значения (объекты) по `key`, и перемещать их в `dirline2`. Вроде все просто, но додуматься не могу.   Реализовал только удаление пока, и дальше не могу додуматься. Это работает на удаление как реализовать что бы не просто удалялось, а по задаче выше?

```
setDirline((prev) => prev.filter((e) => !+key.includes(e.dirline_id));
```

Буду благодарен за конкретный код, ибо с чужих слов не понимаю. Заранее спасибо  с меня лайки!

```
const [dirlines, setDirlines] = useState<IDirline[]>([]);
const [dirlines2, setDirlines2] = useState<IDirline[]>([]);

onDelAndSentDirline2: (key) => {
  setDirlines((prev) => {
    const removed: any = [];
    const filtered = prev.filter((e) => {
      if (e.dirline_id === +key) {
        removed.push({ ...e });
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    });
    setDirlines2((prev2) => [...prev2, ...removed]);
    return filtered;
  });
  console.log(dirlines);
  console.log(dirlines2);
},
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что это за свойство `dirline_id` в коде? Из описания следует что у объектов в массивах есть только свойства `key` и `value`...

Comment: считай что оно и есть. key и dirline_id одниковы

Comment: По условиям задачи, они не могут одинаковы если `dirline_id` является числом (в таком случае, как минимум типы значений различаются) - ведь учитывая то что может быть выбрано несколько элементов, в `key` предполагается список значений (массивом/строкой) - я добавил ответ который исходит из этого. Если же в `key` передается одиночное значение, то вообще весь код получается неверным и тогда его надо полностью переписывать...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по строке кода с `key.includes` (и утверждению что такое выражение работает) - значение `key` вероятнее всего является **массивом**, а не примитивом.
Если это верно, то обращаться с данным значением надо соответственно его типу (а не приводить его к числу унарным плюсом `+key` при сравнении):

```
onDelAndSentDirline2: (keys) => {
  const keysSet: any = new Set(keys.map(Number));       // преобразуем в список чисел (`Set` оптимизирован на чтение, это ускорит проверку по сравнению с `includes`)
  setDirlines((prev) => {
    const removed: any = [];
    const filtered = prev.filter((itm) => {
      if (!keysSet.has(+itm.dirline_id)) return true;   // если в списке такого id нет, оставляем объект (не переносим его в `dirline2`)
      removed.push({ ...itm });
      return false;
    });
    setDirlines2((prev2) => [...prev2, ...removed]);
    return filtered;
  });
  console.log(dirlines);
  console.log(dirlines2);
},
```

Если же аргументом передается **строка** с перечислением айди (это маловероятно, но все же у строк тоже есть метод `includes`) - то строку надо разбивать по разделителю, преобразуя в массив перед проверкой... иначе будет некорректный результат в ситуациях совпадения значения `dirline_id` с любым из десятичных разрядов числа в списке id (например, `1` и `'4,8,16'` => ложное совпадение).

Comment: Огромное спасибо, вы лучший , сейчас работает))

Comment: @ВасилийСюткин, рад что помогло! Пожалуйста, обрати внимание что ответ все же вынужден угадывать некоторые подробности задачи, отсутствующие в вoпросе. От указания подробностей всем лучше: с ними и участникам вoпрос понятнее, и ты быстрее получаешь ответ.